# Unable to Connect to Azure using Certificate thumbprint with Connect-AzAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, identity, powershell-az-module

When I am trying to connect to Azure Powershell it is throwing error.

```
$Thumbprint = '<<CertificateThumbprint>>'
$TenantId = '<<TenantID>>'
$ApplicationId = '<<App registration ID>>'
Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -Tenant $TenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

Steps Performed:

1. Created App Registration.
2. Created KeyVault in Azure Portal.
3. Created Certificate in Keyvault.
4. Added above created App Registration in Access Control with All certificate access related permissions.
5. Downloaded uploaded above created certificate in App registration and then executed above powershell script.

Below error I am getting:
Connect-AzAccount: No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Could not find tenant id for provided tenant domain 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'. Please ensure that the provided service principal 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' is found in the provided tenant domain.

Note: Replaced Thumbprint, App Id and tenant id with dummy values here.

I have few powershell scripts in my web application and I need to execute those scripts with out providing user name and password and other sensitive information.

Comment: The error suggests you skipped step 6: installing the certificate on the machine running the script

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Thank you for your response. Following your comment, I installed the certificate on the local machine, but I'm still encountering the same error. Additionally, do we need to install the certificate anywhere else for web access? Are there any further steps I might have missed to access it on the local machine?

Comment: Most networks require a Credential to complete a connection.  Do not get Authentication and Credentials confused.  Not sure if you server requires Windows Credentials (older) or OAUTH2 (newer).  I will explain both.  Windows Credentials you create an encrypted Credentials using the Username and Password.  The encrypted credentials is safe because it cannot be decrypted.  Your working apps are probably using an encrypted credentials "Under the Hood" and you are not doing it in code.

Comment: OAUTH2 Authentication is a two step authentication.  Step one is to request a token/cookie using again an encrypted user/password.  Step two is to make a query using the token.  Most Azure server have switched from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 is supported on Windows, MAC, and Linux.

Comment: Certificates are used for many purposes.  Often different Certificates are used for both HTTPS (secure using TLS) and for Credentials.  When HTTPS is used before the HTTP request is sent TLS is used to create an encrypted connection.  Then the Request is sent only if TLS passed.

Comment: Your error indicates the TLS failed.  TLS the server sends a certificate block containing the names of the possible Certificates.  The client can choose any one of the certificates in the block.  The client can also choose a specific certificate.  Your code is  asking for certificate $Thumbprint and it may be the server does not have this certificate in the block.  You have to add the certificate to the server as well as the client.